# Python - use format string length variable instead of fixed one?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

For example I can do this:

```
"%.2s" % ('aaa')
'aa'
```

or

```
"%.1s" % ('aaa')
'a'
```

But how can I make that part like `.2` variable, so I could pass any number and it would format accordingly, like if I would pass something like:

```
"%.%ss %" (1, 'aaa') # Pseudo code
'a'
```

Comment: I woul take a look over String.format method : https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Specify the width as `*` and the actual width will be taken from the next positional argument:

```
"%.*s" % (1, 'aaa')
```

The [`str.format()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) is more flexible still, you can interpolate *any* parameter, not just the width:

```
"{:.{width}s}".format('aaa', width=1)
```

Demo:

```
>>> "%.*s" % (1, 'aaa')
'a'
>>> "%.*s" % (2, 'aaa')
'aa'
>>> "{:.{width}s}".format('aaa', width=1)
'a'
>>> "{:.{width}s}".format('aaa', width=2)
'aa'
```

The extra placeholders can be used for any element making up the format specification:

```
>>> "{:{align}{width}s}".format('aaa', align='<', width=4)
'aaa '
>>> "{:{align}{width}s}".format('aaa', align='>', width=4)
' aaa'
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks. Both solutions are good, though first one seems like is more readable in this case (at least for me).